# Send email to change the password after interval of time using workflow in Sugar CRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I have requirement to send an email to user to change the password after 90 days using workflows . How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the "password management" screen under the Admin menu.  Its at the top of that screen.

Comment: hello ken brill ... I want to send an alert to change the password

Answer (score 0):

in Admin Go To "Password Management" and below find "User-Generated Password Expiration", there you can set the expiration days.

Comment: no its not like that i want to send an alert automatically after 90 days to change the password